# Back button issue in login module

Tags: android, android-studio, back

Let say I have 2 forms in my app. let say loginForm and mainForm. In loginForm allows the user to enter his/her username and password then goes to mainForm. From mainForm is I click the back button it will go back to loginForm and now my **issue** is from loginForm if I will click back button it goes again to mainForm without logging in.

What is the best to make this correct?

**loginForm**

```
EditText edtU = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.txtU);
EditText edtP = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.txtP);
Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btLog);
btnLogin.setOnclickListener(new OnclickListener).......{
    if(u.matches("ryan") && p.matches("biugos"){
      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),mainForm.class);
      startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your answer is not what I mean. My problem is when I clicked back button from mainForm it will go back to loginForm and when I clicked the back button from loginForm the application should be close not to go back in mainForm unless he hit the login button with valid username and password

Comment: You only have two activities. If you click back in login, suppose it will quit the app.

Comment: Yes exactly Sir

Comment: You want to quit the app when back button in loginPage clicked ?

Comment: Yes Sir. what is the code for that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After passing the intent use finish like

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityName.class));
finish();
```

and use on back pressed to close the system.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I'd like the finish(); after startActivity .

Answer (score 0):

First, without correct info, you should not let mainForm start;
Second, you should finish self after start other activity if you don't want user to use it again.